# Google sheets to UI

Tags: website-design

So I did a battery management project that sends data to the IFTTT webhook that displays the data on google sheets. I have 7 data that constantly update onto 3 google sheets. I use Arduino to run my C++ code. However, it was suggested that I implement a website er improve the user interface by having nicer data visualization.
But I'm new to this, and I'm doing Electrical and electronic engineering and do not know where to start on this type of user interface. Are there any suggestions on where I can learn this type and what websites I can use to bring my data from google sheets to a better user interface? Friends recommended I try google sheets API to react website. Thank you in advance for your help**strong text**

Comment: This question is not suitable for this site, check the [help] for a reason why. Unfortunately, I am not sure if there are any SE sites that this question would work on.

Comment: Hello Muthiah, and welcome to UX.SE. In order for this community to try to help, we need to know more about your goals and purpose for the user interface is. As of right now, you've said a lot about the technologies you're using, but that unfortunately doesn't really matter to the end user. You mentioned that this is a "battery management project." Please feel free to [edit] your question and remove all of the implementation details, and replace them with details as to what your project actually does, and what your users needs are. Thanks!